# How to detect a click on a slide in Swiper?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, swiper.js

I have an Angular 2 component which contains a slider from the Swiper package. I want to know which slide (its index) I have clicked on. Trying to follow [Swiper documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#events) I have this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import Swiper from "swiper";

@Component({
    selector: "challenges",
    templateUrl: "challenges.component.html"
})
export class ChallengesComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public mySwiper: Swiper;
    public slides = [
        "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/",
        "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/",
        "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/"
    ];

    constructor() { }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination",
                type: "bullets",
                clickable: true
            },
            on: {
                click: function(){
                    console.log(this.mySwiper.clickedSlide);
                }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I click on one slide, it gives me this error `this.mySwiper is undefined`. Why, if `this.mySwiper` is a class member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is in the wrong context. In the documentation it says:

> Please note, that this keyword within event handler always points to Swiper instance

Try without `mySwiper`, only `this.clickedSlide`.

Comment: Precisely for what the documentation says, I understand that we need `this` prefix in order to access swiper properties (like `clickedSlide`). In fact, without prefix, after testing it, it says `mySwiper is undefined`.

Comment: I got it mixed up, since `this` points to the Swiper Instance the `mySwiper` shouldn't be needed, I edited my answer can you try that way?

Answer (score 1):

Without any effort you can change `function` to `arrow function` and your function scope will be binded to `this`. Thus you can access swiper this way!

Another solution is with ViewChild decorator @ViewChild('swiper-container')